# I am trying make a custom user signup form and getting following error while making this

Tags: django

**I am trying to extend the user model**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

    class RegisterUser(models.Model):
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        sector = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**and tried to create a form for the signup**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import RegisterUser


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = RegisterUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'phone_number', 'sector')
```

** These are the only changes I made I am getting the following error:**

```
raise FieldError(message)
```

django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for RegisterUser

Answer (score 0):

`UserCreationForm` is expecting a username field in your model. You'll need to either change the form or make your own one that uses email.

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm)